# Downloading Files using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to write a simple example to allow me to download files from my Google drive using VB.net

I have tried to translate the C# code but I am getting a couple of errors that I cannot seem to solve.

Any help would be gratefully received

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Download()

    Dim storageService = New StorageService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = "APP_NAME_HERE"})
    Dim getRequest = storageService.Objects.[Get]("BUCKET_HERE", "OBJECT_HERE")

    Using fileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("FILE_PATH_HERE", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged()
        getRequest.Download(fileStream)
    End Using
End Sub
Private Shared Sub Download_ProgressChanged(ByVal progress As IDownloadProgress)
    Console.WriteLine(progress.Status & " " + progress.BytesDownloaded)
End Sub
```

The errors are that StorageService is not recognised and neither is IDownloadProgress.

I have all the Include statements and I can log in using my credentials in another area of codeS

Comment: If you put the caret *inside*, for example, `IDownloadProgress` and press `ALT+ENTER`, does the popup suggest something useful?

Comment: To have it recognize IDownloadProgress, add an import statement:
Imports Google.Apis.Download

Comment: Thanks for that. That has removed the Idownload issue but left me with 2 issues. The StorageService is not recognised and there are no helpful suggestions about that and the Line under the Using Filestream is missing a parameter for the Download_ProgressChanged call

Comment: You also need `Imports Google.Apis.Storage.v1` for `StorageService`. Also; what happens if you pass `getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged` back into the `Download_ProgressChanged()` function? So `getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged(getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged)`?

Comment: Thanks for that. That fixes the storage service issue. But do you know what goes in the "BUCKET_HERE" and  "OBJECT_HERE"? I have managed to get the code to work by ignoring the Progress changed bit for now (I think that this should be a handler anyway) but I am guessing what the bucket and object should be and my file is being downloaded with zero bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The code you are using is not for downloading files from Google Drive; it is for obtaining files from Google Cloud Storage.*

#### More Information:

After looking over your question I realised that you're trying to translate code that downloads data from Google Cloud Storage, not from Google Drive. These aren't the same thing and one can not be used for the other. Here I will provide the fixes for your code, and how to authenticate with Google Drive using VB.NET also.

It is also something to note that depending on whether you want to download a native Google Drive file (Docs/Sheets/Slides/etc) or just a file stored there, as native Google Drive files can not be downloaded directly, and must be exported to a download-compatible format such as `.docx` or `.csv`.

#### Code fixes for Google Cloud Storage:

As a compilation of what has already mentioned in the comments above, you are missing two imports for methods in your code:

```c#
Imports Google.Apis.Storage.v1
Imports Google.Apis.Download
```

As you also asked; the `BUCKET_HERE` and `OBJECT_HERE` are [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets) and [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#objects) from Google Cloud Storage - these respectively are containers for data, and the data pieces themselves.

#### Downloading a file from Google Drive:

To download from Google Drive, rather than from Google Cloud Storage, you need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive).

Google provides a Quickstart on how to [set up a project for the `.NET` framework](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet), but their example is specifically for C#. There is comprehensive library documentation for the .NET Drive Library which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/index.html). The main pages of interest, however, are:

1. [Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource.html)
2. [`GetRequest` Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1GetRequest.html)
3. [`ExportRequest` Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1ExportRequest.html)

#### Code snippet:

To get you started here's a code snippet including imports and creating the Drive Service:

```vb
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Dim Scopes() As String = {DriveService.Scope.Drive}
    Dim ApplicationName As String = "Your-Application-Name"
    Private Service As DriveService = New DriveService

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim creds As UserCredential
        'Store your credentials file in the project directory as 'credentials.json'
        'Don't forget to include it in your project
        Using Stream = New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            'Creates a token file for this auth, make sure to delete it and re-auth 
            'if you change scopes
            Dim credentialFile As String = "token.json"
            creds = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(Stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    New FileDataStore(credentialFile, True)).Result
            Console.WriteLine("Credentials saved to: " + credentialFile)

        End Using
        'Create Drive API service.
        Dim Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With
            {
                .HttpClientInitializer = creds,
                .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
            })
        'Define parameters of request here, depending on whether you need to use
        'the get or export methods
        Dim fileId As String = "your-file-id"

        'File processing goes here!
    End Sub
End Module
```

Give the Quickstart a look to understand how to set up a project and get your credentials.

#### References:

- [Key Terms | Cloud Storage | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms)

  - [Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets)
  - [Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#objects)
- [Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive)

  - [.NET Quickstart | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource.html)

  - [Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.GetRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1GetRequest.html)
  - [Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ExportRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1ExportRequest.html)